# Laravel Passport - Specify Database Connection

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-passport

is it possible to specify which database Passport uses? I have 2 databases, the second being the one that contains all the Laravel stuff (Users, Passport, etc).

When trying to login using my VueJS front-end I'm getting this error because it's looking at the default database.

```
"SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'portalto_dbase.oauth_personal_access_clients' doesn't exist (SQL: select exists(select * from `oauth_person
```

How can I have all user authentication stuff to go through the second database?

Answer (score -2):

Just go to config/auth.php and uncomment those lines (and update them with your values).

[image]